# MAMP does not start servers. OS X 10.10.5

Tags: wordpress, apache, mamp

I follow the guide of http://www.lynda.com/WordPress-tutorials/Installing-Running-WordPress-MAMP/361682-2.html and trying to get MAMP servers started.

But when i push the start servers button i'm prompted for user password, i write password and a loading icon is there for 3 sec and nothing happens?

What can i do?

Changing envvars file to _envvars does not help.
https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/yosemite-mamp/

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Setting MAMP to use default port setting made it work. It also let me know that other software is using port 8888.

[image]